# File storage not working. Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to save a `.txt` file in a folder named `txts` inside my public folder but the method i'm using is not working:

```
$txt_nombre = 'nomina_'. $extras['desde'] .'_'. $extras['hasta'] .'.txt';
$txt_contenido = '';

foreach ($personal as $per) {

    $txt_cadena = 'BNC ' . $per->cuenta_nomina . ' ' . $per->netos . ' ' . $per->cedula_identidad;
    $txt_contenido .= $txt_cadena . "\n";

}

Storage::put('public/txts/'. $txt_nombre, $txt_contenido);
```

It doesn't even throw an error, my function keeps running but the file is not being saved. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem)

> By default, the  public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public.

Looking at your code, assuming that you haven't changed default configuration, your file should be created in `storage/app/public/public/txts/` folder.

I am not sure how Laravel's Storage abstraction handles non-existing folders so you might want, for test, try using just `Storage::put('file.txt', "content")` and see if it's being created in `storage/app/public` folder

Comment: So, if i remove the `public/` it will look for a folder called `txts`, right? I've done that (i created that folder too) but it does not work either.

Comment: Are you looking in correct "public" though? 
it's in storage/

Comment: Yes i am. Also, this piece of code: `Storage::put('file.txt', "content")` does nothing.

Comment: Are you on Laravel 5.6? 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem
This piece of code is puting contents into file.txt file.

Comment: Well, I restarted the server and it worked instantly, i don't know why. My file is being is saved to storage folder and that works just fine for me. Thanks a lot!